# Tkinter - Class containing buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `Tkinter` app in which I would like to include some buttons in a frame, and then place this frame in the main window.

However running the code returns just an empty window. So I guess I miss completely how to build a `Tkinter` app with modular classes.. The atomic code is:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.navbar = NavBar(self)
        self.navbar.grid(row=0, column=0)

class NavBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.fetchDataBtn = tk.Button(self, text='Fetch data')
        self.filterDataBtn = tk.Button(self, text='Filter data')

        self.fetchDataBtn.pack(padx=5, pady=10, side=tk.LEFT)
        self.filterDataBtn.pack(padx=5, pady=20, side=tk.LEFT)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I thus wonder what I miss. I searched but cannot find duplicates ..(if they are some, you can point out and I will close the topic).

NB: I am using Python 2.7.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you don't pack (or grid or place) your `MainApplication` instance.
Since your `MainApplication` extends the `tk.Frame` class, its instances are widgets, and thus need to be packed into their master.

```
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)     <--- here: where does it go in the root?
    root.mainloop()
```

Pack it and it will work:

```
app.pack()
```

Comment: My preference is to `pack()` after `init` i/o outside the class.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque The problem with doing so, is that you lose control over the way your instances are positioned. What if you want to use `grid` instead? For example, you want to put four instances of the same widget as a square. What do you write at the bottom of their common `__init__`?

Comment: I understand, thank you RightLeg, I learned something useful.

Answer (score 1):

You must put the navbar in the parent frame, using `pack`, or `grid`:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        self.navbar = NavBar(self)   
        self.navbar.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.pack()             # <-- here ---------

class NavBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.fetchDataBtn = tk.Button(self, text='Fetch data')
        self.filterDataBtn = tk.Button(self, text='Filter data')

        self.fetchDataBtn.pack(padx=5, pady=10, side=tk.LEFT)
        self.filterDataBtn.pack(padx=5, pady=20, side=tk.LEFT)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApplication(root)
    # app.pack()   # <-- or here for a better control of the placement of several instances
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Credits to @RightLeg for pointing out an initial mistake.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: Where does it go, if you don't?

Comment: The problem is not what you describe. Granted, this "solves" the problem... but the logic is not here. The navbar's parent **is** the `MainApplication` instance, not the latter's parent. According to that logic, every widget's parent should be the root... The problem (check my answer) is that the `MainApplication` instance needs to be packed as any other widget. So the reason why OP's code was not working, is that it was missing a call to `app.pack()` (or `app.grid()`, if it makes any sense).

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thank you. I corrected my answer.